# Gigabit card only supports 100 Mbps?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ethernet

My `Dell Inspiron 17R 5720` running on `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS` has a `gigabit ethernet` card, but it is only capable of utilizing `100Mbps`.

I tried another laptop that pulls `150` on the same cable, so I'm pretty sure that my computer is the issue.

I ran some commands:

```
description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: enp3s0
   version: 05
   serial: REDACTED
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw ip=192.168.1.13 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:26 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f1404000-f1404fff memory:f1400000-f1403fff
```

Why is it only capable of using `100Mbps` when it clearly says `Gigabit Ethernet Controller`?

Comment: What does it connect to? Both sides have to be able to handle gigabit Ethernet, or else they will downgrade to the fastest common link speed.

Comment: @ErikF cat5e cable directly into the carrier modem/router.

Comment: If your modem/router is old or doesn't support the latest DOCSIS, etc. the Ethernet port on it (the modem side) may only be a 10/100 and not Gigabit.

Comment: What says `ethtool enp3s0` (or whatever the interface name is)?

Comment: @xenoid "Supported link modes: 10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full"

Comment: Please add the full output to the question. But there could be a problem with the Gigabit support even on Windows, see [this](https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General/Dell-Inspiron-17R-5720-NO-gigabit-available/td-p/3976695).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not necessarily a gigabit Ethernet card.

Realtek has both 1G-capable and 100M-only versions of the same product and uses the same PCI VID:PID for both – therefore resulting in the same "product name" under *lspci*. The only way to distinguish them is by looking at capabilities detected by the driver via `ethtool`.

*(Side note: when checking capabilities via ethtool, ignore the absence of 1G in "Link partner advertised"; the Linux driver appears to actually mask this out if the local device isn't 1G-capable itself. Only look at "Supported link modes" for the card's capabilities.)*

It is unfortunately common for Dell Inspiron laptops to only have the 100Mbps variant of the chip, and you will find this mentioned [in the spec sheet](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/inspiron-17r-5720/manuals) under "Communications" (direct [pdf](https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_inspiron_laptop/inspiron-17r-5720_setup%20guide_en-us.pdf#page=3) link).

[image: Spec screenshot]

USB 3.x Ethernet adapters (dongles) based on the AX88179 chipset are a reliable alternative.

Comment: When running "ethtool" I get this: "Supported link modes: 10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full". Seems you're right.